# Visual Studio git clone always use LF for a file

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We use TFS 2013 here (Version 12.0.30324.0) and we use Visual Studio 2013. We have a project with many TXT files for bulk insert.

When cloning using Visual Studio a few of these files always are cloned with LF line ending instead of the usual CRLF. This breaks our BULK INSERT which is very picky about eol.

Setting `.gitattributes` didn't help

Setting `git config --global core.autocrlf true` didn't help

It always returns with LF termination. The problem seems to be related to the presence of some characters in the file. When they are not there Visual Studio behaves normally setting CRLF, but when they are it sets LF no matter what configurations I have.

Here's how to reproduce it:

1. Create a `test.txt` file with the following content `Associação de países da África, Caribe e Pacífico` with a `CRLF` character at the end
2. gid add, commit and push it to TFS
3. Delete project from your disk
4. git clone the project
5. `test.txt` now has a LF ending instead of the original CRLF

No matter what, this will always return a file with LF.

MSYSGIT with CLI behaves normally, it clones the file with the regular CRLF ending, the problem seems to be with the Visual Studio 2013 git client. I can report that the same happens with Visual Studio 2015.

What could it be? I really have no idea what I can do to solve this, I believe it might be a bug with the git client used in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sounds like a bug indeed.  Would it be possible to provide me with some example files that trigger this behavior?  You can email them to me at `ethomson@microsoft.com`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you set in your `.gitattributes`?  I feel like `* text eol=crlf` should be a workaround here.

Comment: First I tried to `* text=auto`, it didn't work. Then I tried to force it with `*.txt eol=crlf`, didn't work either.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I tried it with `* text eol=crlf` but the files are still cloned with LF as EOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in binary detection, where we are erroneously determining that a file with some non-ASCII UTF-8 characters is binary.  This bug was [fixed in libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/0161e096a30912e0721cf3e6446595d3400d55b7), which is the basis for our Git support in Visual Studio.  This should be fixed in the upcoming VS 2013 Update 5 and in Visual Studio 2015.

Since we are detecting the file as binary, forcing line endings to a particular type will not work.  (Those would only work on text files.)

Unfortunately, this means that there is not a known workaround.
Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I shall add that TFS 2013.2 has the same behaviour, in our environment the problem we have is that the build agent clones the repository and some text files used to BULK INSERT during DB publishing come with LF endings, breaking the build.

Comment: This hasn't changed at all in VS2015, and certainly isn't the answer. VS checkouts from TF git still don't use the correct line endings

Comment: @ekw What do you mean?  How are your `.gitattributes` settings configured?

Comment: * text=auto.  global.autocrlf=true . We had to fix this by re-syncing all the line endings on master and then merging the new line-endings down to every branch. It was impossible to change branches otherwise.

Comment: Indeed that sounds completely unrelated to _this_ issue that was a simple bug in binary detection - an excellent bug report, in fact, that was since fixed in the underlying Git library that VS uses.